# Pronunciation of the name, " Leonhard Euler "

Tags: pronunciation, names, surnames

In almost every source I know, *Euler* has been pronounced as /ˈȯi-lər/ . Nevertheless, in a number of books translated to other languages, it is mentioned as: /ˈjuːlər/ . I doubt in it incorrectness, but have not found any source to prove it. Is this pronunciation correct or not?

Furthermore, pronouncing the word *Leonhard*, are we supposed to say the *h* letter, too?

-
Thank you in advance

Comment: The German pronunciation of eu is /oi/ and the h of Leonhard is pronounced. But there is no rule how you have to pronounce foreign names. Yet in mathematic circles I think the pronunciation of Euler is with /oi/.

Comment: He was German-speaking Swiss so the pronunciation of his name isn't really on-topic here. English Wikipedia is correct according to how I was taught, but it's not surprising that some tests translated from English get it wrong.

Comment: You pronounce it the way Leonhard pronounced it.

Comment: @HotLicks: since Leonhard probably spoke 18th century Swiss German, it's quite likely even the Germans today don't pronounce his name the way Leonhard pronounced it. :-)

Comment: What @rogermue said.

Comment: The youtube channel Numberphile seems to prefer Yoo-ler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In 1905, according to the [Century Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=gTElurCu-WYC&pg=PA2025&dq=dictionary+eulerian&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2266H8t7LAhWIGz4KHeaUAC4Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=dictionary%20eulerian&f=false), *Eulerian* was pronounced /juˈliːrɪən/ (rhyming with *Shakespearian*). So presumably, in 1905 *Euler* was pronounced /ˈjuːlər/. (*Yooler*, for those who can't read IPA.)

The English-speaking mathematical community has long since realized the error of its ways, and started pronouncing Euler's last name using the modern German pronunciation, /ˈɔɪ.lər/. We still usually leave out the /h/ in his first name, and put a /d/ on the end. (The German pronunciation is more like /leːɔnhart/.) But from the OP's comments, this newer pronunciation has not spread to other languages that borrowed the English pronunciation when it was still Anglicized.